# Wordpress Permalink for Application

Tags: wordpress, web-config, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

**Please read this first:
When i activate my custom permalinks on main blog, everything works well.
But i activate permalinks on sub blog, nothing works even wp-admin panel. I got 500 error.**

I have blog on main website on IIS and opened new application under this. I load my wordpress on this applcation without any problem. But when i activated permalinks for this application too, i got 404 error.

My main website config;

Permalink pattern = /%category%/%post-name%/

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
       <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
         <match url=".*"/>
         <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules>
      <remove name="RewriteModule" />
      <add name="RewriteModule" />
    </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="analytics"></location>
    </configuration>
```

As you can see i have main-web-site/analytics for my sub blog. All permalinks works fine on main website but not working on sub blog. When i activate permalinks, sub website creating web.config file and after that i got 500 error. After i delete this web.config file, i can browse on sub blog but when i click to links i got 404 error.

and this is my sub-blog web config;

Permalink pattern : /archives/%category%/%post-name%

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
     <match url="*"/>
      <conditions>
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
       <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any helps would be nice.

Thanks already! :)

Comment: I'm no Windows expert, so I'm sure someone else will chime in, but in my limited experience, with IIS, you need isapi_rewrite as "mod_rewrite" which wordpress requires is an Apache module.

Comment: I installed iis isapi rewrite module 2.0 on IIS7 already and problem is the same